# trouble using httphandler to retrieve image url

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to write a httphandler to retrieve image url and later display it on a image control i am  using this code but its not working

```
OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection(
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnection"].ConnectionString);
     mDB.Open();
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select pProductId from Products where pProductId=" + context.Request.QueryString["ImageID"], mDB);
     OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     rdr.Read();
     context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr[0]);
     mDB.Close();
     context.Response.End(); */
```

sorry that i caused a confusion earlier in the SELECT statement the pProductId does not contain the URL of the image instead pProductImage is the field that contain the URL. i am using the Id to identify which image to display accordingly.

this is my expected output:

```
<img src="ImgHandler.ashx?pProductId=2" alt="" />
```

i cant place image this is the link to my error msg:https://i.stack.imgur.com/X25M2.jpg

Comment: Are you including the actual image in the SELECT statement?

Comment: Given the typos above it could be any number of things. What is the real code that is being used? What behavior are you experiencing? Is there an exception?

Comment: is pProductId an URL? that seems strange. Also, if you want to display an URL, you can just write an IMG tag followed by an SRC attribute, not an array of bytes.

Comment: sorry folks i am rather weak in asp.net and c# language. as for @SimonMourier i think your right, what i hope to achieve is to retrieve the url from my database and display the image using id as a identifier.

Comment: it's normally nice to post both expected output AND actual output

Comment: My car wont go... Here is a picture of the license plate and my key ring what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a two steps answer.
In the page, you can do something like this:

```
        using (OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            mDB.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select pProductId from Products where pProductId=" + context.Request.QueryString["ImageID"], mDB))
            {
                using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    context.Response.Write("<img src=\"ImgHandler.ashx?pProductId=");
                    context.Response.Write((int)rdr[0]);  // I suppose pProductId is an int, adapt accordingly
                    context.Response.Write("\" />");
                }
            }
        }
```

and in the HTTP handler implicitly triggered, something like this:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            mDB.Open();
            // select the file data (I put pData here as a placeholder, and assume it will be a byte[])
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select pData from Products where pProductId=" + context.Request.QueryString["ImageID"], mDB))
            {
                using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";// put the content type here
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the using pattern which ensures proper resources cleanup once used. Also, ideally you could cache the data on the client using proper cache HTTP headers (like if-modified-since) but this is another story ...

Comment: the above code where should i placed, it under the aspx file ? because when i place it there it wont work

Comment: The handler code should be placed in a new .CS file, and the class MyHandler should be declared in the web.config where HTTP handlers are declared. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Error message when i place that under my .ashx[Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'pProductId='.]

Comment: This is an issue with your database system syntax. That has nothing to do with ASP.NET/Handlers, etc.

Comment: sorry simon i dont really understand the code you written should be placed in a new .CS file not a .ashx file?

Comment: <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="ImgHandler.ashx" type="ImgHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's almost correct. The ASHX token is just used to redirect to the class. The *type* attribute should be the class full type name like 'MyNamespace.MyHandler'.

Comment: where can i find my namespace, do i create it under myhandler class or?

Comment: i don't understand this line
// select the file data (I put pData here as a placeholder, and assume it will be a byte[])
the field i have contain a url like this " ~/Images/pic1.jpg" it is not a image file so i don't think byte is necessary? i just need to get this string from the field. pls help